# Find a $t\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\left( (1-\frac{1}{k})^t-(1-\frac{2}{k})^t \right) \geq \frac{1}{4}$

Tags: approximation, upper-lower-bounds

Edit: I'm clarifying my task and question.
I have an algorithm that I want to prove is a
$\frac{1}{4}$-approximation.
I proved that:
$$
\mathbb{E} [f(S_t)] \geq \left( (1-\frac{1}{k})^t-(1-\frac{2}{k})^t \right)f(S_{OPT})
$$
Where $S_t$ is the solution at iteration $t$ and $S_{OPT}$ is the optimal solution, and $k\in\mathbb{N}$ is a given constant.

Now, I need to show that there is a choice of $t\in\mathbb{N}$ such that:
$$
\mathbb{E} [f(S_t)] \geq \frac{1}{4}f(S_{OPT})
$$
So, I need to show:
$$
\left( (1-\frac{1}{k})^t-(1-\frac{2}{k})^t \right) \geq \frac{1}{4}
$$
My attempts so far:

1. I tried bounding it with the property
   $$
   (1-\frac{1}{k})^k\leq e^{-1}
   $$
   but I can only do it for the left expression and I'm not sure what to do with the right one.
2. I saw that for $t=k \cdot \ln 2$ I get:
   $$
   (1-\frac{1}{k})^{k \cdot \ln 2}-(1-\frac{2}{k})^{k \cdot \ln 2}
   \longrightarrow_{k\rightarrow\infty}
   (e^{-1})^{\ln 2}-(e^{-2})^{\ln 2}=\frac{1}{4}
   $$
   but I need $t$ to be an integer, I tried bounding it with the ceiling and floor functions but I got stuck again.
3. As the comments suggested, I tried doing a taylor expansion, but I didn't get the same results like the in comments, and I'm not sure why.

Comment: Please show some of your attempts...what have you tried? What part are you stuck on?

Comment: What’s your attempts?

Comment: I've edited the post :)

Comment: I don't think it is true.  If $k \gg t$ you have on the left approximately $(1-\frac tk)-(1-\frac {2t}k)=\frac tk$

Comment: I have a solution but I shall not post as long as you do not show any of your working.

Comment: I don't have anything other than what I already written, I'm stuck on this without any idea how to move forward. @ClaudeLeibovici

Comment: $k$ is fixed and I control $t$. @RossMillikan

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Time for your answer!

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer. Done

Comment: You need to get the quantifiers in the right order.  You are trying to prove that for each $k$ there exists a $t$.  The first line says there exists a $t$ such that for all $k$.  Those are different.  The first is true, the second is false.  It is important that $k$ is chosen before $t$

Comment: You are correct. Iv'e edited the post

Answer (score 1):

*You are on the right track.*

Consider the function
$$F(k,t)=\left(1-\frac{1}{k}\right)^t-\left(1-\frac{2}{k}\right)^t$$ Its derivative cancels at
$$t_*=\frac{1}{\log \left(\frac{k-2}{k-1}\right)}\log \left(\frac{\log \left(\frac{k-1}{k}\right)}{\log
   \left(\frac{k-2}{k}\right)}\right)$$

Expanding at least for large values of $k$
$$F(k,t_*)=\frac{1}{4}+\frac{\log (2)}{4 k}+\frac{1+2 \log (2)+2 \log^2 (2)}{16
   k^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{k^3}\right)$$ Notice that
$$\frac{\partial^2 F(k,t_*)}{\partial k^2}=\frac{\log (2)}{2 k^2}+\frac{\log (2) (3+\log (4))}{4
   k^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{k^4}\right)$$ and
$$t_*=k\log(2)+\frac 12(1-3\log(2))-\frac{3+\log (4)}{24 k}-\frac{5+6 \log (2)}{48 k^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{k^3}\right)$$

*Now, it is your turn !*

Comment: Hi, can you please explain what you did in the 3rd step? what does 'Expanding at least for large values of  $k$' mean? (English is not my first language)

Comment: @LotanAmit. Same for me ! What I made is a Taylor series expansion for "large" values of $k$ to approximate the function and it derivatives.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? I can't see how you made these transitions

Comment: Where did the $\log (2)$ came from? I can't seem to get it in my calculations

Comment: When expanding I get:
$$
( 1-\frac{1}{k})^t-(1-\frac{2}{k})^t = \left(1-\frac{1}{k}t+\frac{t(t-1)}{2!}\frac{1}{k^2}+O(\frac{1}{k^3}) \right)
- \left( 1-\frac{2}{k}t+\frac{t(t-1)}{2!}\frac{4}{k^2}+O(\frac{1}{k^3}) \right)
=  1+\frac{1}{k}t-\frac{3t(t-1)}{2!}\frac{1}{k^2}+O(\frac{1}{k^3})
$$